# Skip marshalling with @XStreamConverter ToAttributedValueConverter when value is null

Tags: java, xml, converters, xstream

I have the following POJO which I would like to marshal using the @XStreamConverter ToAttributedValueConverter:

```
@XStreamAlias("MyPojo")
@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = {"content"})
public class MyPojo{

  private final String content;
  private final String attribute1;
  private final String attribute2;

  public UniqueReportIDIss(String content, String attribute1, String attribute2) {

    this.content = content;
    this.attribute1 = attribute1;
    this.attribute2 = attribute2;

  }
}
```

The ToAttributedValueConverter marshals this nicely to:

```
<MyPojo attribute1="foo" attribute2="bar">content</MyPojo>
```

This is just what I need in 99% of all use cases. However, in one particular use case, if the content is null, the marshaling must be skipped.

Currently, if the value is null, it results in:

```
<MyPojo attribute1="foo" attribute2="bar"></MyPojo>
```

The Javadocs of ToAttributedValueConverter explicitly state that null values are permitted, thus the question: How can I extend ToAttributedValueConverter so that it skips marshaling when the value is null.

Thanks
Walter

Comment: Link to the Javadocs: https://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/extended/ToAttributedValueConverter.html

Comment: Perhaps you could extend ToAttributedValueConverter and modify the marshal method as you want?  https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/blob/master/xstream/src/java/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/extended/ToAttributedValueConverter.java

I have not tried it, just a suggestion

Comment: I tried it already. Problem is that at the time the marshal-method is called, it's already too late. The start tag has already been written at that point and so, no matter what you do in the marshal-method, you will end up with <MyPojo></MyPojo>. Unless there are some tricks, I'm not aware of...